# loading clojure-contrib

Tags: import, clojure, classpath, jvm-arguments, clojure-contrib

I'm new to the whole JVM thing, and trying to play with clojure. I'm attempting to load clojure-contrib and failing:

```
# in bash
$ java -cp /path/to/clojure.jar:/path/to/contrib.jar clojure.main

# in REPL
user=> (require 'clojure.contrib.math)
nil
user=> (sqrt 2)
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: sqrt in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:10)
```

Any pointers will be great - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but it seemed like a namespace issue. The solution I employed was this:

```
;; for REPL
user=> (ns user (:use clojure.contrib.math))
nil
user=> (sqrt 2)
1.4142135623730951
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put **refer** after **require** which will map all the symbols into current namespace

```
(require 'clojure.contrib.math)
(refer 'clojure.contrib.math)

(sqrt 2)
(expt 2 3)
```

For detailed intro you may read wikibooks article. 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Concepts#Refer_and_Use

Comment: Excellent.  Seamlessly works with Clojure scripts being embedded into Java apps for me too (I'm using Netbeans, with Clojure and Clojure-contrib accessed as "libraries")!